# Correct way to check for a key inside JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I know there are different ways to check for a key inside a JSON object.

```js
const person = {
  name: 'john',
  age: 25,
  isTeenager: false
}

if (person.name) {
  console.log('name exists')
}

if (person.hasOwnProperty('age')) {
  console.log('age exists')
}

if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(person, 'isTeenager')) {
  console.log('isTeenager exists')
}
```

These all work fine, but which is the correct and most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: It depends, do you want an own property or is an inherited property OK?

Comment: You left out `if ("name" in person)`

Comment: `if (person.name)` will fail if the value of the property is a falsey value. You can use that when you know that all valid values are truthy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. hasOwnProperty() is correct way to define.
2. hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean denoting whether the object has the defined property as its own property.

```
const person = {
  name: 'john',
  age: 25,
  isTeenager: false
}

if (person.hasOwnProperty('age')) {
  console.log('age exists')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise, `if(obj.value != undefined)` would be the "best";

```js
var perf = require("perf_hooks").performance;

var obj = {
  iExist: "hi"
};

var start = perf.now();
if(obj.iExist != undefined) { // changed from obj.iExist to obj.iExist != undefined because of potential problems with booleans.
}
var end = perf.now();
console.log("basic if: " + (end - start));

var start1 = perf.now();
if(obj.hasOwnProperty('iExist')) {
}
var end1 = perf.now();
console.log("hasOwnProperty : " + (end1 - start));
```

Output:

```
basic if: 0.06810665130615234
hasOwnProperty : 4.006890296936035
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can't always rely on truthy-falsy check as you mentioned in the first example. It will fail on `boolean` properties if the value is `false`

```
if (person.isTeenager) {
  console.log('key exists')
}
else{
  console.log('key not exists')
}
```

You will get falsy on this. So always use `hasOwnProperty` method